# Looking for "big & brassy" band finales

Tags: jazz, orchestra, brass, wind-band

I apologize for the crude example, but the last part of ["Kyle's Mom's a Bitch"](https://youtu.be/i9AT3jjAP0Y?t=77) (timestamp: 1:17) is a direct reference to the trope I'm talking about.

I've heard finales like these in countless musicals but I've never been too clear on which genre or subgenre of band music they belonged to.

Can you think of any similar examples?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for lists are unfortunately not well-suited for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Probably belongs on Music Fans.